# Accessing MySQL database from C

Tags: mysql, c

I am very new to MySQL.

Linux.

I want to create a database in MySql and using a C program I would like to populate the data from a text file into the database.

I couldnt find much information on this :(

Is there any clear material on this? Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL comes with a client library and an ODBC connector.  The client library is documented here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-functions.html, the ODBC library is here  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-odbc.html

Answer (score 1):

Google? This is the first entry I get by searching for "Accessing MySQL database from C":
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html

Comment: Probably 99% of questions on SE sites can be answered by sufficient googling. Suggesting that as an answer is not helpful. The idea behind SO is to be *better* *than* Google for seeking answers to programming questions.

Comment: I disagree with your statement, and, anyway, I also provided a useful link.

Answer (score 0):

The C API library is distributed with MySQL and is the basis for most other language bindings. Everything you need should be in the MySQL manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c.html

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few good tutorials for this. Here are a couple resources.

- [MySQL C API](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/)
- [Official C API Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api.html)
- [Tutorial for those with decent programming background](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/MySQL-Programming-C-API.html)